# Best constant in the endpoint 1d Sobolev embedding

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, constants

Consider the following inequality: 
$$\tag{1}
\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)} \le C_{\rm{best}} \|f\|_{H^1(\mathbb R)}, $$ 
where $\|f\|_{H^1(\mathbb R)}^2=\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2 + \|f'\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2$ and 
$$C_{\rm{best}} = \sup\left\{ \frac{ \|f\|_{L^\infty} }{\| f
 \|_{H^1}}\ :\ f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)\right\}.$$ 
Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in Fourier space one sees that $C_{\rm{best}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$:
$$\begin{split}
|f(x)|=\left|\int_{\mathbb R} \hat{f}(\xi) e^{i x \xi}\frac{d\xi}{2\pi}\right|&\le \sqrt{\int_{\mathbb R} |\hat{f}(\xi)|^2(1+\xi^2)\, \frac{d\xi}{2\pi}}\sqrt{\int_{\mathbb R} (1+\xi^2)^{-1}\,\frac{d\xi}{2\pi}}\\
&=\|f\|_{H^1}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}.
\end{split}$$

> Note that
>   $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}= \frac{ \|e^{-|x|}\|_{L^\infty} }{\| e^{-|x|}
>  \|_{H^1}}.$$
>
> **Primary question**. 
>   Is it true that $C_{\rm{best}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?
>
> **Secondary question**. If the answer to the previous question is affirmative, is it true that equality is attained in (1) if and only if $f(x)=A e^{-|x+x_0|}$ for some $A, x_0\in \mathbb R$?

The Fourier approach presented above is not suited to those problems, because it uses the rough estimate $|e^{i x \xi}|\le 1$. An affirmative answer to those questions would be interesting for me, since I have never seen an example of an extremal function that is not smooth.

Comment: Your arguments indeed show that $C_{best} = 1/\sqrt{2}$. It cannot be worse due to your Fourier estimate and it cannot be better due to $f(x) = \exp(-|x|)$.

Comment: To answer your second question, take any $g$ which attains equality.
W.l.o.g., we can assume $\|g\|_{L^\infty} \le 1$ and $g(0) = 1$. In fact, it minimizes $\|g\|_{H^1}$ under all $g$ with $g(0) = 1$. This problem can be solved by the usual tools of calculus of variations (Euler equations).

Comment: @gerw: Thank you very much, I got it.